# How can I filter text iterating over different lists with RegEx terms in Python?

Tags: python, regex, loops, python-re

There is an API service that receives over 6000 JSON files. Each of those JSONs has 11 variables.

**Here comes the problem:**

Variables `s` and `d` are strings. Variable `s` are names and `d` are items. There are 4 lists that have RegEx values. The lists do not all have the same length.

In one case if variable `s` matches a certain name from a list of 3 names, and `d` matches one specific value, the flag should be False.

In the rest of the cases if variable `s` or `d` match a RegEx value in the 4 lists, it should return a `flag` as True plus a `label` (1, 2, 3).

This is the first function that I tried and failed:

```
def flag(s_text, d_text, filter_a, filter_b, filter_c, filter_e):
    flag = False
    label = ''
    special_names_list = ['^OSCAR', 'ADRIAN\b', 'MORALES.*']

    #CONSIDER THAT ALL TEXT IN THE REGEX FILTERS IS IN CAPITALS
    s = s_text.upper()
    d = d_text.upper()

    for n in special_names_list:
        if re.search(n, s) and re.search('BALL', d): #This is the one only case
             flag = False
             label = ''

    #The following loops are over the lists containing RegEx filters
    for a in filter_a:
        if re.search(a, s):
            flag = True
            label = 2
    for b in filter_b:
        if re.search(b, d):
            flag = True
            label = 2
    for c in filter_c:
        if re.search(c, d):
            flag = True
            label = 1
    for e in filter_e:
        if re.search(e, d):
            flag = True
            label = 3

    return flag, label
```

This is the second function that I tried, and also failed:

```
def flag(s_text, d_text, filter_a, filter_b, filter_c, filter_e):
    #All text is either received or converted in upper case.

    flag = False
    label = ''
    special_names_list = [r'OSCAR.*',r'ADRIAN.*',r'MORALES.*']
    s = s_text.upper()
    d = d_text.upper()

    # I thought to create a regex dictionary where the value of each key has the label I expect to be returned.

    regex = {} 

    for a in filter_a:
        regex[a] = 2
    for b in filter_b:
        regex[b] = 2
    for c in filter_c:
        regex[c] = 1
    for e in filger_e:
        regex[e] = 3

    for n in special_names_list:
        if bool(re.match(n, s)) == True and bool(re.search('BALL', d)) == True:
            flag = False
            label = ''
            break
        else:
            for k, v in regex.items():
                if bool(re.search(k, s)) == True or bool(re.search(k, d)) == True:
                    flag = True
                    label = v
                    break

    return flag, label
```

The correct function should return a tuple containing the `flag` boolean value and the `label` depending on each case, there is one case where the value is `''`.

This code does not really work for all cases, especially the first one. I have been testing it to try all possibilities I can think. I have been very careful to input values that will match the RegEx.

I think there is a way to construct that function easier, there is also something I am missing on the logic behind the loops to iterate better.

Extra info: the keyword `'BALL'` does repeat in one of the filter lists. This means that for `s` `OSCAR`, `ADRIAN` and `MORALES` when `'BALL'` is present in `d` `flag` should be `False`, but when there is any other value for `s`, then `flag` should be `True`.

In my code, when I pass, OSCAR and BALL it returns flag as True, instead of False.

Comment: Note `'ADRIAN\b'` must be turned into `r'ADRIAN\b'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, correct me if I'm wrong: I have been learning python on a mac using jupyter notebooks, I have not ever used `r'REGEX' `since it seems to be needed for Windows environments. Am I going to have problems in the future if I don't use them?

Comment: Raw string literals do not have anything to do with OS. `'ADRIAN\b'` is a string literal that holds `ADRIAN` text and then a BACKSPACE char. A `r'ADRIAN\b'` raw string literal contains `ADRIAN\b` text (where `\b` is a word boundary regex escape construct).

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, and chance, I found the answer and understood several errors on the code and logic:

- **Understanding raw strings**

As Wiktor had explained to me RegEx `'ADRIAN\b` should be transformed to `r'ADRIAN'\b`. I did some reading about it and understood why it wasn't matching my keywords.

- **If statement for 2 variables**

For my first IF statement, I was evaluating a certain word to be matched in 2 different RegEx terms lists. I was also using `IF` and `AND` in the same statement. I failed to understand that, while the condition was well written, it was not going to loop over the 2 RegEx lists independently but at the same time. This means that, to match, both values had to be found at the same step.

The workaround was 2 separate IF statements and an extra variable that would be True or False. Like this:

```
for n in special_names_list:
    if re.search(n, s):
        validation = True

if re.search('BALL', d):
     validation_2 = True

if validation = True and validation_2 = True:
     return flag, label
```

This would be able to pass the one-case condition if a certain word (`'BALL'`) was found on the variable d, and a certain name in the special names variable list.

- **JSON and RegEx**

The RegEx filter rules came in a JSON file imported using `pd.read_json`. While in python `\b` does a certain function, in JSON I had to add an extra backslash `\\b`. Other RegEx conditions didn't need extra attention, just the backlash.

- **Loops and `break`**

I do not fully understand the use of `break` in a loop, or what it exactly does, but I changed all of them to `return` as I hoped it would stop the loop if a condition was met. And it did.

- **Testing**

For every loop, either `for` and/or `if` I created `print` statements to figure out where the case was being matched.

This is the final function that worked:

```
def flag(s_text, d_text, filter_a, filter_b, filter_c, filter_e):
    s = s_text.upper()
    d = d_text.upper()

    flag = False
    label = ''
    validation = False
    validation_2 = False

    if re.search(r'OSCAR.*\b|ADRIAN.*\b|MORALES.*\b', s):
        print('match name')
        validation = True

    if re.search(r'BALL\b', d):
        print('match special condition')
        validation_2 = True

    if validation == True and validation_2 == True:
        return flag, label
    else:
        for a in filter_a:
            if re.search(a, s):
                print('match filter_a')
                flag = True
                label = 2
                return flag, label
        for b in filter_b:
            if re.search(b, d):
                print('match filter_b')
                flag = True
                label = 2
                return flag, label
        for c in filter_c:
            if re.search(c, d):
                print('match filter_c')
                flag = True
                label = 1
                return flag, label
        for e in filter_e:
            if re.search(e, d):
                print('match filter_e')
                flag = True
                label = 3 
                return flag, label
        return flag, label
```